# Ruby gets method has any limit on input size?

Tags: ruby

In my IRB if i run `input = gets` and give more than 4095 characters input to it, it takes only 4095 characters. Is there any limit that ruby can read only 4095 characters from STDIN.

Comment: Try `STDIN.read` and stop it with Ctrl-D

Comment: Which version of ruby are you using ?

Comment: ruby-2.1.7 and Ubuntu 15.10 @lcguida

Comment: Same happens for STDIN.read @PandaCool

Comment: Well, long shot here, but since ruby adds a end of line when using gets, making this a total of 4096 chars, I would guess this has something to do with native types in C.

Comment: I think so, when i tried the same code in C and the same thing is  happening...@lcguida

Comment: Most likely this is a limitation of your TTY (see [How to read over 4k input without new lines on a terminal?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131105)). Try to [pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) the data to Ruby instead of entering / pasting it directly into your terminal.